# storm inlet drain blocked

Tags: drain

Residential storm inlet overflowing and blocked in the car park.
Removed water but was unsure what to do next or how the mechanics of the inlet work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I would suspect that this leads directly to the city's storm water drainage system, that said system is blocked, and that it's the city's responsibility to take care of it. I'd notify the city and ask them to check on it next time it rains.

Comment: With the amount of mud that it looks like was in there it definitely needs a call to the city, usually there is a trap so the crud settles then the water flows out. If it is plugged down the pipe the city I lived in used large suction booms and pulled the leaves and mud back up then flushed it, sometimes an auger was necessary.

Comment: Once you've contacted the city and they've fixed it, please come back to write up what happened as an answer to your question. That's not only perfectly acceptable 'round here, it's actually expected.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that is a pic taken standing over the storm drain looking down into it.  How interesting that someone put a sewer cleanout in there.  Don't mess with that cleanout unless you want the problem to get worse real quick, I am sure it has nothing to do with handling rainwater.

Do you know where this is supposed to exit?  Is it running underground to an outlet downhill somewhere?  If you don't know where it goes to you probably shouldn't mess with this one.

If you know where the outlet is you MIGHT be able to put a pump in there and run a garden hose with a pressure nozzle on it down into there with the water on full and the pump keeping the drain empty and if there's no sharp bends you might be able to clear the blockage out if it's just mud.  I would start with the exit end, though.  If you cannot find it that doesn't mean it's not there, more likely it's a victim of years of neglect and is buried.

Sometimes these things ended up running into a sewer line or sometimes into an underground "french drain"  To do this job right if you can't find the outflow you need a sewer endoscope and a sewer line locator the tooling alone is a couple grand.